# Can't Print " * " in C

Tags: c

for some reason I am unable to print out "* " in my program. I want to print out * if the condition is met. the condition is if the rainfall that day is greater than the average.

under the mean column, i am getting weird symbols. i tried debugging to decimals and get -112 for ascii. i dont understand but i tried researching!

I am new to C so please be understanding. Just learned like 2 days ago!!.

Here is my code :

```
//Assignment one 9/20/2018
//Anthony Lomaistro and David Luong 
//luongd5@student.lasalle.edu
//lomaistroa1@student.lasalle.edu

#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    int n = 0; //counters for the loops
    int x = 0; // counter for the loops 
    int counter = 0; // counter whenever i need to keep track of increments
    int days_input = 0; // how many days we are keeping track of
    int number_of_days = 0;
    double rainfall_input = 0;
    double rainfall_amount = 0; // how much rainfall per day
    double rainfall_average = 0; // average of rainfall
    double rainfall_total = 0;
    double rainfall_counter = 0; // count how many days it rained above the average
    int correct = 0;
    double rainfall_array[50];//array that contains the user input
    char rainfall_condition[50]; // array that contains the *

    double sum = 0;
    double average = 0;
    double percent_days = 0; //rainfall % above average
    double valid = 0;
    double valid2 = 0;

    printf("Welcome to Lomaistro and Luong's Rainfall Program \n");

    printf("How many days would you like to keep track of? Please enter a value between 1 and 50: #%d:", n + 1);

    //printf(number_of_days);

    while (valid == 0) {
        scanf_s("%d", &number_of_days);
        if ((number_of_days > 50) || (number_of_days <= 0)) { // come back to this, this doesnt do anytihng
            printf("Invalid value, please enter in a day that is between 1 and 50 \n");
        }
        else {
            valid = 1;
        }
    }

    //getting the user to enter in the rainfall 
    for (x = 0; x < number_of_days; x = x + 1) {
        valid2 = 0;
        while (valid2 == 0) {
            printf("Enter rainfall (in inches): ");
            scanf_s("%lf", &rainfall_amount);
            if ((rainfall_amount >= 0) && (rainfall_amount <= 10)) {
                valid2 = 1;
                rainfall_array[x] = rainfall_amount;

            }
            else
                printf("Please enter in a valid rainfall amount between 1 and 10");
        }
    }
    //computing average
    for (n = 0; n < number_of_days; n = n + 1) {
        sum += rainfall_array[n];
        average = sum / number_of_days;
    }
    printf("Mean daily rainfall(in inches): %lf", average);

    //seeing if the * should be the array or not
    for (n = 0; n < number_of_days; n = n + 1) {
        if (rainfall_array[n] > average) {
            rainfall_condition[n] = "*";
            rainfall_counter = rainfall_counter + 1;
        }
        else
            rainfall_condition[n] = "empty";
    }

    // print out the thing
    printf("\n Days \t Amount \t >Mean \n");
    printf("==============================\n");
    for (n = 0; n < number_of_days; n = n + 1) {
        printf("%d \t %f \t %c \n", n + 1, rainfall_array[n], rainfall_condition[n]);

    }
    percent_days = rainfall_counter / number_of_days;
    percent_days = percent_days * 100;
    printf("Number of days that rained above average : %f \n", rainfall_counter);
    printf("Percentage of days that rained above average: %f%% \n", percent_days);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? If GCC, *always* compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror` to enable all warnings and treat warnings as errors.

Comment: i use visual studio. i got my situation fixed though. ill keep that in mind

Comment: I know you fixed *this* issue. I'm trying to help avoid the *next* one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rainfall_condition` is an array of `char`, but you're putting a pointer to a string literal in there when you use `"*"`. Use `'*'` for a character literal instead. To be more specific, this line:

```
        rainfall_condition[n] = "*";
```

Should be:

```
        rainfall_condition[n] = '*';
```

Turn some warnings on in your compiler; the first line (what you have now) isn't valid C code and you should be seeing a diagnostic message to that effect.

Edit: now that I've read more of the code, it appears you want either a `*` or an `empty` in that column? In that case you want to change the variable declaration to:

```
char *rainfall_condition[50]; // array that contains the *
```

And then change the print statement to:

```
    printf("%d \t %f \t %s \n", n + 1, rainfall_array[n], rainfall_condition[n]);
```

Comment: Thanks! itt worked
just to be clear, %s means string right? if so, when would i use %c vs %s?

Comment: Is there something in the documentation that's confusing? `%s` is the conversion specifier for a string, and `%c` for a character.

Comment: no i just wanted to clarify. i see my mistakes now. thanks